# Bash completion broken on short options

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I've created my own bash completion function. I've made several edits. The completion itself suits me, but I have broken the auto space after the short options `-a`, `-p`, `-h`

Meaning, when I type `editcfg -fil`<kbd>TAB</kbd> it autocompletes to `editcfg -file`  (space after the `-file`).
However, if I type `editcfg -p`<kbd>TAB</kbd>, it won't autospace after the `-p`.

Function:

```
_editcfg () 
{ 
    local cur prev opts presets u_opts;
    COMPREPLY=();
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}";
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}";
    opts=("-n" "-p" "-file" "-a" "-verbose" "-version" "-h");
    presets=("default" "empty");
    u_opts=();
    for i in "${opts[@]}";
    do
        for j in "${COMP_WORDS[@]}";
        do
            if [[ "$i" == "$j" ]]; then
                continue 2;
            fi;
        done;
        u_opts+=("$i");
    done;
    case ${prev} in 
        -p)
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${presets[*]}" -- ${cur}));
            return 0
        ;;
        -file)
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -fd -- ${cur} 2>/dev/null));
            return 0
        ;;
        -h | -version)
            u_opts=();
            return 0
        ;;
    esac;
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${u_opts[*]}" -- ${cur}));
    return 0
}
```

What did I miss?

Thanks

Comment: If you `continue 2` *after* adding the current option to `u_opts` does that fix it? Does `editcfg -file<TAB>` add the space?

Comment: Adding the `continue 2` doesn't fix it. `editcfg -file<TAB>` also doesn't complete it. Seems only when a partial option is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the 2nd `for` loop and it worked fine:

```
_editcfg () 
{ 
    local cur prev opts presets u_opts;
    COMPREPLY=();
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}";
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}";
    opts=("-n" "-p" "-file" "-a" "-verbose" "-version" "-h");
    presets=("default" "empty");
    u_opts=();
    for i in "${opts[@]}"; do
        for ((j = 0; j < COMP_CWORD; ++j)) do
            if [[ "$i" == "${COMP_WORDS[j]}" ]]; then
                continue 2;
            fi;
        done;
        u_opts+=("$i");
    done;
    case ${prev} in 
        -p)
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${presets[*]}" -- ${cur}));
            return 0
        ;;
        -file)
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -fd -- ${cur} 2>/dev/null));
            return 0
        ;;
        -h | -version)
            u_opts=();
            return 0
        ;;
    esac;
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${u_opts[*]}" -- ${cur}));
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Definitely works. Don't understand why :(. Also with `for j in "!${COMP_WORDS[@]}" ...`

Comment: With your code when you input `-p<TAB>` the array `COMPREPLY` would not include `-p` then Bash would think the *current word* (`-p`) cannot autocomplete to any string in `COMPREPLY` so Bash would not change the *current word* at all. With my code, `COMPREPLY` would include `-p` so Bash would know that the *current word* (`-p`) can autocomplete to a string (`-p`) in `COMPREPLY` unambiguously so it would autocomplete the string (from `-p` to `-p`) and insert a SPACE.

Comment: It's kind of challenging for me to explain this kind of thing in English. :)

Comment: I understand what happens, just not why your code does and mine not :) nevermind. at least it works :) Thanks!